# javascript - what does ${} do?

Tags: javascript

I have seen ${ } being used in many javascript codes. What exactly does this do?

For example:

```
 updateDisplay(){
        if(this.operation != null){
            this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = ${this.previousOperand} ${this.operation};
        }
        this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
    }
```

Why would we not use + to concatenate in this case?

Comment: `${ }` called [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) - Very brief explanation in this link - Also, *Template literals are enclosed by the backtick (` `)*

Comment: Are you sure that they not wrapped in backticks?

Comment: Are you sure there is not ` backticks ` around those? The code you have posted is a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, there should be backticks around them. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's called a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It achieves the same thing as concatenation but in a more readable manner:

```js
const a = "Hello"
const b = "."

console.log(`${a} World${b}`)
```

Comment: Are there any differences between using template literals and using '+' to combine the strings? Is there any case where it would be preferable to use one over the other?

Comment: Using templates is vastly more readable that string concatenation.